# Xcode storyboard discrepancies across version control

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am having quite the annoying problem with my Xcode storyboard. I have a project controlled through svn version control and everything seems to be copying over fine with the normal merges and commits. When I make a change to the storyboard and commit it, say just a dummy label, and my partner updates his project with the latest commit it shows up fine, just like it is on my own project. However, when my partner adds a dummy label and commits, my update does not show the project on the screen. It only shows the label on the scene viewer. This is also happening with tableviewcontroller's inside of other view controllers, or really anything that he updates. When the app is run the app shows everything that it is expected too, but this does not make sense as the storyboard file is not showing these things. I am not sure what is happening as nothing seemed to be wrong early on. Any help or guidance is appreciated. Here is a picture detailing what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/by6ce.jpg

If you would like more info about this please leave a comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you just need to update the size class when you or your partner opens up your project like so:

[image]

and choose whatever size you find appropriate for your app

Comment: Thank you that is the solution!